# How to identify skill books in Kingdoms of Amalur: Re-Reckoning?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-re-reckoning

As I'm rummaging through shelves, is there a way to identify books as skill-raising?  I've been looting wildly, reading everything I come across, and haven't encountered anything that has raised a skill (AFAIK).  I assume there would be some kind of popup message telling you that you've read a book which increased a particular skill, and haven't seen that so far. I've been playing a while, am at level 20.  I'm also not picking up most books, just reading them, does that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The skill books are **clearly identified** as such in their titles. There are only nine across the world (barring a known bug which sometimes spawns an extra one), and most are quest rewards or otherwise locked behind progress on side quests, especially the Faction quests. So they're quite rare. The ones that aren't quest rewards are generally hidden fairly well, and Amalur is a big place. At level 20, you almost certainly have access to the Sagecraft book, which is

> in a well outside St. Hadwyn's mission (you need Detect Hidden 2 to find things in wells).

You can go find that, so then you'll know what the skill books look like.

Comment: Thanks! Yup, that book's title is "Skill Book (Sagecraft)"